# Node & Redis: Cannot pull more than 46 records in a list

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, scalability, node-redis

We have a problem that simply we cannot solve for weeks.

We are using Node.js on Heroku, openredis for our Redis server, 'node-redis' for the Node Redis client.

In our mobile app project, we have a redis list called 'user_list' where it contains the keys in our redis db #1 (list is in the db #1) as well. We show the locations of the users on a map by first pulling the id's from the user_list and later on for each id in list we make a 'get' request.

However the issue is when we are trying to make a 'smembers user_list' we cannot retrieve the entire elements in user_list. After number of 46 records it returns like ',,,,,,,,'

We literally tried everything and when we gradually increase the elements inside the list it works but when we put 100 elements we simply cannot retrieve

What could be the problem?

Comment: if you connect to your redis from redis-cli and run smembers there, what does it return? what does scard return? if you spop from the set, do you get all the values?

Comment: @akonsu Yes, everything works perfectly fine on those but as soon as the concurrency level hits 100 per sec node-redis starts to fail. Fail!

Comment: @akonsu, did you solve the issue? im interested.

Comment: @mzalazar it is not my question, ask Ali